# Can't reach observablesArray instantiated by ko.mapping in javascript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Here is example:
http://jsfiddle.net/valin/W4ubQ/

As you can see array instantiated by function (`this.features`) is working. But array instantiated by ko.mapping (`this.featuresFromJS`) is working only for view, but not inside javascript function. How should I instantiate `featuresFromJS` or whatever to compute `lowTotal`?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help:

```
function objFeatures(name, price) {
    return {
        name: ko.observable(name),
        price: ko.observable(price)
    }
}

var AppViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.featuresFromJS = ko.observableArray();

    self.features = ko.observableArray([
    new objFeatures("Feature1", 20),
    new objFeatures("Feature2", 50)]);

    var data = '[{"name":"Feature3","price":20},{"name":"Feature4","price":50}]';

    ko.mapping.fromJSON(data, {}, self.featuresFromJS);

    self.lowTotal = ko.computed(function () {
        var total = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.featuresFromJS(), function (item) {                
            alert("hooray!");
            total += item.price();
        });
        return total;
    }, self);

    self.grandTotal = ko.computed(function () {
        var total = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.features(), function (item) {
            total += item.price();
        });
        return total;
    }, self);
};

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Comment: Thanks! I got wrong mapping attributes, I was very close trying `ko.mapping.fromJSON(data, {}, self.featuresFromJS());` ^_^